# Neo4j labeltokenstore and labelscanstore files

Tags: neo4j

What does Neo4j store in the files:

- neostore.labelscanstore.db
- neostore.labeltokenstore.db
- neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of available `labels` in the database and the association `label<->node`